# How to play wave files in X11

Tags: linux, x11, embedded-linux

Please help, I need to play wave files in X11. Is there any API in X11 like PlaySound in windows? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aplay`, `mplayer`, `vlc`, `mpg123`, `mpg321`, etc.

For raw (non-mp3, non-compressed) `wav` files, simple `cat` should work:

```
cat file.wav > /dev/dsp
```

If you need API way to do it, this is simple example how to [play `wav` file using ALSA API](https://gist.github.com/ghedo/963382).

However, this has nothing to do with X11.